# If Razorpay payment is pending then what response will it return?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, razorpay

I am using Razorpay integration for my App. Suppose someone's payment status is pending then what will be the response and also If after some time/days payment status is successful then how can I update in my App.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use webhooks and get response through that, if user already paid for the order then you better refund or create order for the user if transaction is success.